# SyntaxError: Identifier '__dirname' has already been declared

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Hi I am trying to create a static folder in my server.js for image upload but when I declare the const __dirname = path.resolve() the error message

"const __dirname = path.resolve()
^

SyntaxError: Identifier '__dirname' has already been declared"

get thrown

```
require('dotenv').config()
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const server = express()
const { notFound, errorHandler } = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware')
const { connectDB } = require('./config/db')

const productRoutes = require('./routes/productRoutes.routes')
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes.routes')
const orderRoutes = require('./routes/orderRoutes.routes')
const uploadRoutes = require('./routes//uploadRoutes.routes')
connectDB()

server.use(express.json())

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('API is running.........')
})
//Routes
server.use('/api/products', productRoutes)
server.use('/api/users', userRoutes)
server.use('/api/orders', orderRoutes)
server.use('/api/upload', uploadRoutes)

server.get('/api/config/paypal', (req, res) =>
  res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID)
)

const __dirname = path.resolve()
server.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))

applicationCache.server.use(notFound)
server.use(errorHandler)

//Listen
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
server.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} port ${PORT}`)
)
```

Anyone please help thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is solved if you remove the following line:

```js
const __dirname = path.resolve()
```

`__dirname` has already been declared in the `global` namespace.

More information you can see in [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

Answer (score 1):

Server.js lies here

> App/backend/server.js

You might be looking for something like this

> App/upload

If you use __dirname You Get

> App/backend/upload

__dirname in a node script returns the path of the folder where the current JavaScript file resides.

If we rename __dirname to __variableOfChoice. We get

```
    const __variableOfChoice = path.resolve()
    server.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__variableOfChoice , 
    '/uploads')))
```

> App/upload

> I was running This command from ./App "start": "node backend/server",

Tested on Node version v12.17.0
[Here How I did it](https://github.com/Malik-Idrees/proShop/blob/main/backend/server.js)